# Flexbox overflowing container height in IE11

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Firstly, let me say that unfortunately I do have to support IE11 still and I don't believe this is a duplicate question, although I have found a few that were kinda similar.

I have a simple modal window which contains 3 flexible components in a column, header, footer and main.

The plan is that the outer box should grow as the content grows, until it is 80% of the height of the screen, at which point the middle section of the modal which is set to overflow-y:auto should get a scrollbar and the main modal will not get any taller.

Here is my markup

```
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">Header</div>
    <div class="modal-main">
      <div>Content goes here, could get very long</div>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fairly standard stuff. The modal is set to flex and the header and footer are fixed height. The middle section is set to grow and shrink as necessary. The main thing is that the .modal should never overflow the .modal-wrapper.

I have a jsfiddle set up and it's tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and iOS and it's working fine if you drag the bottom right box height up and down you'll see how it is supposed to behave. IE11 though is a mess.

https://jsfiddle.net/jonhobbs/sf6untnt/3/

Now, I have a feeling it may be related to the min-height bug here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview

but I'm not convinced it's exactly that bug because none of the workarounds for that bug seem to work (e.g. using min-height:1px instead of 0, wrapping in another flexbox etc).

Hopefully somebody on SO can take a look at the jsfiddle and see an obvious problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you make it a flex child and use    `flex:0 1 80%;` , it should fixe your trouble with IE :

example

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}

.modal-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex:0 1 80%;/* IE gets it , because the flow is column */
  max-height:80%;/* others such as FF gets it */
  background: white;
}

.modal{
  display: flex;
  flex-glow: 1;/* doesn't exist */
  flex/*-shrink*/: 1; /* good enough */
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.modal-main{
  flex: 1;/* good enough */
  min-height: 1px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.modal-header, .modal-footer{
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 60px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">Header</div>
    <div class="modal-main">
      <div>This content could get very long so I'm going to put a big long div in it</div>
      <div style=" width:100px; height:1000px; background-color:red; opacity:0.1;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sf6untnt/7/